# Adding a Scroll bar to flexbox with overflowing content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have a div that scrolls which is contained within a flex element that's expanded to fill the page.

In my code, the column2 will have lengthy content so we need to have individual scrolls for each column.

This is my current structure:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

BODY.screen-layout-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex.two-col-main-sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.flex.layout-content-default {
  width: 100.0%;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.layout-content-default {
  width: 100.0%;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: none;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  white-space: normal;
}

.content-item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.0px 0 14.0px 0px;
  width: 100.0%;
  padding: 0 0.0px 0 0.0px;
}

.two-col-main-sidebar>.column-1 {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 0.0px;
}

.flex.two-col-main-sidebar>.column-1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: static;
  float: none;
  padding-right: 0.0px;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.two-col-main-sidebar>.column-2 {
  margin: 0 -100% 0 0;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300.0px;
}

.flex.two-col-main-sidebar>.column-2 {
  margin: 0;
  position: static;
  float: none;
  flex: 0 0 300.0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body class="screen-layout-body with-fixed-header">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class=" flex content layout-content-default two-col-main-sidebar">
    <div class="content-item content-layout column-1">Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content</div>
    <div class="content-item content-layout column-2">Column2 which will be 30% of screen</div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

**Note:** What ever the CSS classes are here, generated by tool we cannot modify them, additionally we can add more classes to any of the div's to make it work.

Comment: Your code does very different things than what you described, learn some basics before using flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

Your version is breaking because you have `column-1` set to `width: 100%`.

You can specify the styles without all the nested selectors, too (makes the code simpler to maintain).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.screen-layout-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.content {
  white-space: normal;
}

.content-item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  }
  
.column-1 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
  }
    
.column-2 {
  width: 30;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<body class="screen-layout-body with-fixed-header">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class=" flex content layout-content-default two-col-main-sidebar">
    <div class="content-item content-layout column-1">Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content. Column1 which will be 70% of screen. I need to add scroll bar to this div which will overflow content.</div>
    <div class="content-item content-layout column-2">Column2 which will be 30% of screen</div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```